# ¿Como paso el estado levantado como props desde el componente padre al hijo?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

Este es mi componente App:

```js
import Footer from "./components/Footer/Footer"
import './App.css';

class App extends React.Component{
  state = { TestIsOn: false }

    handleStateUp = (testInOn) => {
        this.setState({ TestIsOn: testInOn })
    }

  render(){
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <NavBar/>
        {this.state.TestIsOn ? <Test /> : <PreTest />}
        <Footer handleStateUp={this.handleStateUp} />
      </div>
    );
  }

}
```

Cómo puedo hacer que el componente Footer renderice un botón u otro (abajo se muestran) dependiendo de si `TestIsOn: false` o `TestIsOn: true` que se encuentra en el componente App? 
Actualmente estoy usando handleStateUp como condicional pero este enfoque no funciona.

```js
class Footer extends React.Component{
   
    render(){
        return (
            <div>
                <footer>
                    <div><p class="atajos-p">
                            Ahorra tiempo con los <a href="#">atajos de teclado</a>
                        </p></div>
                    <div class="start-game-container">
              
                    {this.props.handleStateUp &&<React.Fragment><p>PRESIONA ENTER PARA </p> <button onClick={() => this.props.handleStateUp(true)} >Empezar</button></React.Fragment>}
                    {!this.props.handleStateUp &&<React.Fragment><p>PRESIONA ENTER PARA </p>  <button >Comprobar</button></React.Fragment>}
                    </div>
          </footer>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Aquí el repo online https://codesandbox.io/s/smoosh-wildflower-7yqkv?fontsize=14

Comment: Revisa mi respuesta en donde te explico cual fue tu problema junto con la solución para que te pueda funcionar en forma correcta. Con esto espero a ver aclarado tus dudas. Si la respuesta te sirve no dudes en marcarla para que pueda servir a futuro a otras personas de SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que estas evaluando una función `this.props.handleStateUp` como si fuese un `true` o `false` recuerda que en el componente `App.js` `handleStateUp` es una función que actualiza tu estado local del mismo componente. Ese seria tu error.

**¿COMO LO SOLUCIONO?**

Fácil ! a tu componente `<Footer />` pasale las props correspondientes desde el componente `<App />` seria algo como:

```
<Footer
  TestIsOn={this.state.TestIsOn}
  handleStateUp={this.handleStateUp}
/>
```

Puedes verlo funcionando [acá](https://codesandbox.io/s/zen-tu-gqxlw?fontsize=14)

Answer (score 1):

Lo que puedes hacer es pasar el valor de *TestIsOn* a el Footer a traves de un prop de la siguiente manera

```
  <Footer
      TestIsOn={this.state.TestIsOn}
      handleStateUp={this.handleStateUp}
  />
```

Y en tu componente Footer puedes renderizar un botón u otro dependiendo del valor que le pases en el prop

```
 <div class="start-game-container">
        {this.props.TestIsOn && (
          <React.Fragment>
            <p>PRESIONA ENTER PARA </p>{" "}
            <button onClick={() => this.props.handleStateUp(false)}>
              Empezar
            </button>
          </React.Fragment>
        )}
        {!this.props.TestIsOn && (
          <React.Fragment>
            <p>PRESIONA ENTER PARA </p>{" "}
            <button onClick={() => this.props.handleStateUp(true)}>
              Comprobar
            </button>
          </React.Fragment>
        )}
 </div>
```

Te dejo un [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/admiring-cache-blsd2?fontsize=14) modificando tu ejemplo que esta funcionando